# Online tool for practicing matrix operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I've decided to brush up on Linear Algebra after several years of disuse, and have rediscovered how tedious it can be to write out matrices by hand. Is there some online tool I can use to speed the process, but one that will allow me to work out the solution on my own?

After a quick search, I'm seeing numerous sites offering matrix calculators, but I'm not looking for something that will do all of the work for me - I'm just looking for an easy way to represent the data. At the moment, what I'm reviewing is fairly simple, so I could probably just format something in any given text editor, copy + paste + replace for each row operation, but I'm thinking there may be features that would be nice to have down the road that I'm not yet aware of? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not SAGE or SymPy or other CAS systems? You can also get a pro package like Mathematica, Maple, ... Maybe Wolfram Alpha will also work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions; I'll give them a look - when I originally took a LinAlg course, we worked everything out by hand, on paper. I'm unfamiliar with any of the digital tools at my disposal.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using a Computer Algebra System and dedicating cycles to learning one.